# Limit arithmetic of infinite sequences

Tags: real-analysis

The setup here is that I want to prove:
Suppose ${x_n}$, ${y_n}$ are convergent sequences where $x_n \to L$ and $y_n \to M$.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n}{\lim_{n \to \infty}y_n},$$ where $\lim_{n \to \infty}y_n \neq 0$.

I start off from having: $|\frac{x_n}{y_n} - \frac{L}{M}|$ and want to show that this is less than $\epsilon$ for $n \geq N$.

Since $y_n$ might be undefined for certain values of $n$, I want to choose $N_y^{*}$ such that this is taken care of. We know $M \neq 0.$ Now $\exists N_y^{*}$ such that $|y_n - M| < \frac{|M|}{2}, \quad \forall n \geq N_y^{*}.$ Note that if $y_n = 0$, then $|y_n - M| = |M| > \frac{|M|}{2}$. Therefore, $y_n \neq 0$ for any $n \geq N_y^{*}$.

Now my professor notes that $|y_n| \geq \frac{|M|}{2}$. Why? As long as this is known, I can proceed to reach the statement desired.

Comment: $M = y_n + (M - y_n)$. By the triangle inequality, $\lvert M\rvert \leqslant \lvert y_n\rvert + \lvert M - y_n\rvert$. Can you see the rest?

Comment: Yes I see it now, I've also tried many times the triangle inequality, but didn't see that one.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $M\ne 0$ and that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $N(\epsilon)$ such that $M-\epsilon<y_n<M+\epsilon$ whenever $n>N(\epsilon)$.

If $M>0$, then for $\epsilon=M/2$ there is a number $N_1$ such that whenever $n>N_1$, we have

$$y_n>M-\epsilon=M/2 \implies |y_n|>|M|/2$$

And if $M<0$, then for $\epsilon=-M/2$ there is a number $N_2$ such that whenever $n>N_2$, we have

$$y_n<M+\epsilon=M/2\implies |y_n|>M/2$$

And we are done showing that for $M\ne 0$, there exists a number $N$ such that $|y_n|>M/2$ for all $n>N$.